# Custom Web Player for Spotify

Tags: spotify, spotify-app

As far as I know, it is not possible to develop a Web app (outside spotify.com) providing a custom Web player which plays Spotify songs, am I right?
The only option still seems to be the spotify play button, which is very limited though.

I have just seen, however, this example

1) http://static.echonest.com/enspex/web/ChillRadio/

this one

2) http://lab.possan.se/thirtify/

and this one

3) https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/code-examples/ (see "Play something" snippet)

that seems to use a custom player (2) and 3) are not working for me, though). Is there any non-documented feature?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Spotify Web API provides URLs to 30 second MP3 previews of tracks, which is what these examples are using. This is documented [here](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/object-model/#track-object-full) (the `preview_url` property).

It is not possible to do full-length track streaming on the web with Spotify's APIs.

Comment: I see, I should have realized it, thanks for having pointed it out!
Do you have any information about when they will release the full-length track streaming?