# Streaming a Spotify track when using the Web API

Tags: spotify, spotify-app

I'm not really happy with the Windows Phone Spotify app. I'm looking into developing my own Spotify client using the Web API. It looks like it's not possible to stream a track using the Web API, after receiving the track metadata. Is this conclusion correct? Is there another way to make this work, using the track uri/href/spotify url? Will it become available in Web API in the near future?

Thx Martijn

Comment: possible duplicate of [Custom Web Player for Spotify](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25308751/custom-web-player-for-spotify)

Comment: No, it's not possible. See this question (and a number of others):  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25308751/custom-web-player-for-spotify

Comment: Thanks for you're quick reply! Are there any plans on making this available in the Web API? Or will there be an update for the Windows Phone app, making more features available, like in the desktop client? (Your Music, more info about tracks/albums, play queue control)